# SCSS: Condition in the middle of multiple CSS statements

Tags: less, sass

I am building a mixin for SCSS i would like to know it it is possible to add a aditional value, depending on a argument. This is what i have tried. Everything works, but the @if condition:

```
@mixin fontFace( $fontName, $path: "", $weight: normal, $style: none, $fileName: $fontName, $svg:0 ) {
    @font-face {
      font-family: $fontName;
        src: url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.eot");
        src: url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.eot?iefix") format("eot"), 
                 url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.woff") format("woff"),
                 url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.ttf") format("truetype")
                 @if $svg != 0 {
                    , url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.svg##{$fileName}") format("svg");
                 }else{
                    ;
                 }
      font-weight: $weight;
      font-style: $style;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
@mixin fontFace( $fontName, $path: "", $weight: normal, $style: none, $fileName: $fontName, $svg: false ) {
    $src: url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.eot?iefix") format("eot"), 
          url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.woff") format("woff"),
          url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.ttf") format("truetype");

    @if $svg == true {
        $src: $src, 
                url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.svg##{$fileName}") format("svg");
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: $fontName;
        src: url("#{$path}#{$fileName}.eot");
        src: $src;
        font-weight: $weight;
        font-style: $style;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 sounds like a superb solution, I'am just wondering if it would be possible with something that resembles my syntax...